# Delay initial payment to specific date on Paypal Subscription button

Tags: paypal, delay, payment, subscribe

I am currently pre-selling a monthly subscription service, which will not launch until the 1st June 2015, however I cannot find a way to delay initial payment until 1st June using Paypal Subscription Button. I don't want to charge people two weeks early, as this would result in them being charged early each month. Likewise, I don't want to add a two week trial period, because I'll have to alter the length of the trial each day, as I sign up new people closer to launching the service. Is there anyway to qualify the payment method, without actually taking the payment through Paypal until a specific date, i.e. 1st June?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is indeed available, but only via PayPal's API-based subscription services. (Also known as Recurring Payments and Recurring Billing depending on the service you're using.) Since a trial period wouldn't work here due to its fixed length, you'd need to provide a start date in an API request. This will initiate the billing of the profile on the date provided.

For your scenario, essentially what you'd need to do is create the profile with no trial period while passing the following:

<kbd>PROFILESTARTDATE</kbd> = <kbd>2015-06-01T00:00:00</kbd>

Unfortunately, Subscription buttons do not offer this functionality. Please see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/ for more on creating Recurring Payment profiles using Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I think this is a bit beyond my capability :(